# 2 questions regarding Rack::Timeout (rspec + thread-safety)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, thread-safety

In my Rails application I'm using [Rack::Timeout](https://github.com/kch/rack-timeout) to solve an issue described in this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9976869/timeouts-in-rails-nginx-best-practices). Works fine so far, but I have 2 questions regarding this:

1. What is the best way to test the timeout handling (using rspec)?
2. According to the documentation, Rack::Timeout uses threads so I have to make sure my app is "thread-safe". I know what this basically means in theory -- I have to make sure that no problems occur when two threads operate on the same data at the same time -- but I'm not sure where exactly I have to ensure that. The static datastructures/methods I'm using should not be problematic, but I'm not sure with the database. Does it (or the ActiveRecord classes) need additional configuration?